# Como deserializar XML en C#

Tags: c#, poo

Estoy haciendo una addenda para un XML, recorro el archivo con un split pero he escuchado que la buena practica sería deserializar.
¿como recorro el xml y lo transformo en un objeto para manipularlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La deserializacion no requiere recorrer nada, simplemente tienes que poder mapear el xml con una clase que definas.

Teniendo el xml puede obtener la clase que mapea con esta usando tools como ser

http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

o puedes usar el Visual Studio para obtener la class que se obtiene a partir del xml

[Generate Class From JSON or XML in Visual Studio](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-class-from-json-xml-in-visual-studio/)

La idea es que despues uses

[Cómo serializar un objeto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/szzyf24s%28VS.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Cómo deserializar un objeto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fa420a9y(VS.80).aspx)

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));

FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("myFileName.xml", FileMode.Open);

MySerializableClass myObject = (MySerializableClass)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

donde dice `MySerializableClass` debes indicar la clase que obtienes desde la estructura del xml