# Recoger datos de una variable C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity

Buenas.
Tengo el siguiente código que lee un xml ,y recoge los datos y los guarda en una variable.

```
private void leerxml(){
xElement rootnode= xelement.load(@"C:/xml.xml");
   foreach (xElement chlid in RootNode.Elements())
   {
       if(chield.Name.Localname.Equals("datos"))
       {
           string xml = child.Value.Tostring();
           Debug.Log(xml)
       }
   }
}
```

Mi Xml es este :

```
<libro> 
  <libroEjemplo> 
       <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
       <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
  </libroEjemplo>

  <libroEjemplo> 
       <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
       <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
  </libroEjemplo>  
</libro>
```

En la variable xml,cuando ago el Debug.log(xml) me saca esto:

```
Alfredo Reino alf@ibium.com
Alfredo Reino alf@ibium.com
```

Necesito coger los datos separados,para que luego en otra clase los use,pero no se como hacer para coger los datos individualmente y luego poder usarlos individualmente para mostrarlos en diferentes sitios.
Si alguien tiene alguna idea .. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Quizás te interese [Como deserializar XML en C#](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28539/como-deserializar-xml-en-c), debido a que lo usarás en otras clases.

Answer (score 1):

Aconsejaria uses algo como ser

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _xml = @"<libro> 
                          <libroEjemplo> 
                               <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
                               <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
                          </libroEjemplo>
                          <libroEjemplo> 
                               <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
                               <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
                          </libroEjemplo>  
                        </libro>";

        XElement xdocument = XElement.Parse(_xml);

        var list = from item in xdocument.Elements("libroEjemplo")
                  select new 
                  {
                     nombre = item.Element("nombre").Value,
                     email = item.Element("email").Value
                  };

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.nombre, item.email);
        }
    }
}
```

con al ayuda de `linq xml` puedes pocesar el xml tomando los valores de cada nodo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías primero crear una clase que represente los valores del xml y luego deserializarlo para que te sea más fácil trabajar con la información. Para el trabajo con xml utilizo la herramienta del visual studio (xsd.exe), muy buena que te genera la clase o el xsd (en dependencia de lo que necesites).

Para las transformaciones:
Convertir de c# a xsd: En consola de visual studio 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\xsd.exe" ClassLibrary1.dll /t:Customer

Convertir de xsd a c#: En consola de visual studio
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\xsd.exe" /c /out:d:\ d:\Schema.xsd

Para generar el xsd utilizo de la suite de Altova (XMLSpy) y me saca de un xml ejemplo el xsd.

Estos pasos son para trabajo con xml grandes, para pequeños, como es en el caso suyo, puede directamente hacer la clase, seria algo como esto:

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("libro")]
    public class LibroXml
    {
        [XmlElement("libroEjemplo")]
        public List<LibroEjemplo> Libros { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LibroEjemplo
    {
        [XmlElement("nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("email")]
        public string Correo { get; set; }
    }
```

//Código para el trabajo con los xml.

```
var obj = new LibroXml
{
    Libros = new List<LibroEjemplo>
    {
          new LibroEjemplo
          {
              Correo = "ysilvafdez@gmail.com",
              Nombre = "Yanet"
          },
          new LibroEjemplo
          {
               Correo = "hgrafael@gmail.com",
               Nombre = "Rafael"
          },
          new LibroEjemplo
          {
               Correo = "alf@ibium.com",
               Nombre = "Alfredo Reino"
          }
     }
};    
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LibroXml));

//Para crear un fichero xml:
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("xmlExample.xml");
ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
writer.Close();
//Para leer de un fichero xml
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("xmlExample.xml");
var obj1 = ser.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```