# C# deserializar XML para leer y recoger datos

Tags: c#, xml, unity

Tengo una aplicación en Unity y tengo una clase donde asigno a unos botones un texto.
Quiero que los textos de los botones se importen de un archivo XML.
Tengo hecho esto para leer el XML pero no se como sacar los datos y llevarlos a la otra clase.

Este es mi código :

```
Public void leerXml()
{
   datos libros = null;
   string path= @"C:\libros.xml"
   XmlSerializer serializer = nwe xmlSerializer(typeof(datos));
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
   libros = (datos)serializer.deserialize(reader):
   reader.close
}
```

Este es mi XML

```
<libro> 
  <libroEjemplo>
       <libro1>
          <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
          <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
       </libro1>
  </libroEjemplo>

  <libroEjemplo>
       <libro2>
          <nombre>Alfredo Reino</nombre> 
          <email>alf@ibium.com</email> 
       </libro2>
  </libroEjemplo>
<libro>
```

Creo que eso lo tengo bien y me lee los datos del XML,pero como puedo conseguirlos y llevarlos a otra clase para asignar a los botones los textos del XML?

Comment: No está muy clara tu pregunta. Asumiendo que tras deserializar, en tu objeto `libros` estén los datos correctos, a que te refieres con llevar los datos a otra clase? Lo normal es hagas una propiedad `public Libros` con un getter que devuelva el contenido de la variable `libros` que debería ser  un campo, o sea, estar definida a nivel de clase.

Comment: Arriba puse el codigo del xml,Si el código que puse me funciona bien creo.Hay una opción desde el editor de código que es como depurar código y puedo indicarle una linea con un punto rojo.Cuando ago eso en el edito del codigo en la consola me sale el campo nombre y email con los datos del xml

Comment: tengo una clase donde tengo el codigo ese,y luego otra clase con los botones y el texto.Quiero saber como puedo coger los datos del xml y llevarlos a la otra clase para asignarlos a los botones.Cuando compile la aplicacion ,simplemente cambiando el xml se cambiara el texto de los botones

Comment: Desde la otra clase llamas a `leerXml`? por que en lugar de hacer el método `void` no devuelves lo leido? `public datos leerXml()
{ ... tu codigo .. return libros;}`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como deserializar XML en C#](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28539/como-deserializar-xml-en-c)

Comment: @Davlio creo que el duplicado que indicas no aplica aqui. El problema no parece ser la deserialización de datos, si no como acceder a los datos de una clase desde otra.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document he seguido esos pasos de Kevin Tighe del primer comentario .Lo que necesito ahora es una forma de que los datos del xml los pueda asignar a los botones que estan en otro .cs

Answer (score 2):

Primero te sugiero hacer una modificación a la estructura de tu XML: Amenos que tu aplicación así lo requiera, deberías poder agregar `<libro1>` y `<libro2>` como `<libro>` cada uno, ambos dentro del elemento `<librosEjemplo>`.

```
<libroRaiz>
    <librosEjemplo>
        <libro>
            <nombre></nombre>
            <email></email>
        </libro>
        <libro>
            <nombre></nombre>
            <email></email>
        </libro>
    </librosEjemplo>
<libroRaiz>
```

Basándome en ésta sugerencia:

Yo utilizaría `System.Xml.Linq;` de la siguiente manera

```
// se Carga todo el XML en el objeto libro
XDocument libroRaiz = XDocument.Load("tuarchivo.xml", LoadOptions.None);
//usa éste siguiente para cargar desde texto (string) en vez de un archivo
//XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(texto);

//Obtener objeto librosEjemplo
XElement librosEjemplo = libroRaiz.Element("librosEjemplo");

//Obtener lista de libros dentro de librosEjemplo
IEnumerable<XElement> libros = librosEjemplo.Descendants("libro");

//has un foreach y por cada uno haz lo que tengas que hacer
foreach(XElement libro in libros)
{
    string nombre = libro.Element("nombre").Value;
    string email = libro.Element("email").Value;
    ...
}
```

Lo puse paso a paso para que pudieras apreciar qué hace cada parte, pero puedes hacerlo en una línea:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> libros = XDocument.Load("tuarchivo.xml", LoadOptions.None).Element("librosEjemplo").Descendants("libro");

foreach(XElement libro in libros) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es que tengas una propiedad en la clase donde deserializas el xml que devuelva el valor de lo leido. Sería algo asi:

```
public class LectorXML
{ 
    private datos libros;
    public datos Libros
    {
         get{
            return this.libros;
         }
    }

    public void leerXml()
    {
       string path= @"C:\libros.xml"
       XmlSerializer serializer = nwe xmlSerializer(typeof(datos));
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
       libros = (datos)serializer.deserialize(reader):
       reader.close
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, en la otra clase harias algo asi:

```
LectorXML lector= new LectorXML();
lector.leerXml();
LectorXML.datos libros=lector.Libros;
```

Otra opcion es que tu método `leerXml` devuelva los datos leidos:

```
public datos leerXml()
{
   string path= @"C:\libros.xml"
   XmlSerializer serializer = nwe xmlSerializer(typeof(datos));
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
   libros = (datos)serializer.deserialize(reader):
   reader.close
   return libros;
}
```

Con lo que desde tu otra clase,el código sería algo asi como:

```
LectorXML lector= new LectorXML();
LectorXML.datos libros=lector.leerXml();
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar `DataSets`, A mi parecer son mas sencillos de usar que los propios `XMLSerializer`, aunque tiene sus pros y sus contras.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("miDataSet");
        ds.ReadXml("RutaDeMiXML");

        foreach (DataTable tabla in ds.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La tabla " + tabla.TableName + " Tiene los siguientes campos");
            foreach (DataRow row in tabla.Rows)
            {
                Console.Write("nombre: " + row["nombre"].ToString());
                Console.Write("email: " + row["email"].ToString());
            }
        }
```